# Calling save() on the object of a model in Mongoose doesn't save the record to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some backend code written in Nodejs that identifies the user and sends an OTP to their email.

Before I send the OTP via mail, I want to store it in my MongoDB database, so that I can later validate the user using the OTP.

Here's the NodeJS code:

```
//generates a cryptographically secure 6 digit long code:
const otp = otpgen_function()

//Store the OTP in DB:
const newToken = await new Token({user_id: user_record._id,token: otp})
const saveToken = await newToken.save()
```

Here's the schema of Token:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.ObjectId
const TokenSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user_id:{
        type: ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'mis'
    },
    token:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    createdAt:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now(),
        index: {expires:'15m'}
    }
}) 
module.exports = mongoose.model('Token',TokenSchema)
```

The createdAt field ensures that the OTP is deleted from the DB after 15 mins.

However, for some reason Mongoose doesn't save the OTP record when I call save()

In fact the behavior of save is very... erratic:

- Sometimes it saves the OTP record and it stays there,
- other times it is saved and can be seen in the collection, but
  disappears after a few seconds.
- However most of the time, it just doesn't save the record...

Any ideas as to what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it may be complicated when trying to create a model with its constructor and save it. Have you tried `Token.create()` method ?

Comment: That might work in another scenario I suppose. The reason for my troubles turned out to be something else(solution answered below)

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the index I specified in the  schema:

```
index: {expires:'15m'}
```

Was the source of the problem. Earlier for testing I had kept the expiry to a few seconds. Later, I changed the value to 15 minutes.
However, mongoose didn't update the index in MongoDB, so I had to manually do it by executing the following in my MongoShell:

```
db.tokens.dropIndex('createdAt_1')
```

And then restarted my NodeJS server. Doing these things solved the issue